# Converting polygon to path

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, polygon

On a Windows app store project i have these polygons

```
<Polygon x:Name="AcItemTriangle" Stroke="#aa6861" Fill="#aa6861" Visibility="Collapsed" Points="0,0 28,0 14,35" />
```

and

```
<Polygon x:Name="AcItemTriangle" Points="0,0 28,0 14,35" Stroke="#67a0bb" Fill="#67a0bb" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

I would like to know if there is a way i can convert my polygon points to a Path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L28,0 14,35Z" Stroke="#aa6861" Fill="#aa6861" ... />
```